# Extremely Bizarre Mirror Result?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to use the mirror mod to place hands on a character.

The origin is the direct centre of the scene and the mirror is placed on the Z axis, and yet I get this result:

[image]

The viewport is in direct front orthographic mode. Why is my mirror messed up?

Comment: Have you applied rotation and scale?

Comment: It was the rotation and scale... I really must get in the habit of applying those more often...